# After updating database and sending emails with the updated detail, it send the old details not the newly updated one

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I created an email testing form, it is used  to test update email configurations directly from the admin panel, I put the configuration in the App\Providers\SettingsConfigProvider.php such that when the admin updates the email configuration in the database, the SettingsConfigProvider.php will use those details to send emails. I wish that a test email will be sent as soon as users configures the email an error will be returned to the user if it doesn't send due to some error

The problem is, if you update the database with those information, it won't reflect immediately, instead, it will test the email based on the previous details, it will only use that configuration after you must have made the change twice.
Is there a way I can fix this? Thanks

Below is the boot method of the provider:

```
public function boot()
    {
        if(env('APP_INSTALLED')){
            
        if (Schema::hasTable('settings')) {
            $settings = DB::table('settings')->first();
            //checking if table is not empty
            if ($settings) {
                config([
                    'mail.mailers.smtp.driver' => $settings->mail_driver,
                    'mail.mailers.smtp.host' =>  $settings->mail_host,
                    'mail.mailers.smtp.port' =>  $settings->mail_port,
                    'mail.mailers.smtp.encryption' =>  $settings->mail_encryption,
                    'mail.mailers.smtp.username' =>  $settings->mail_username,
                    'mail.mailers.smtp.password' =>  $settings->mail_password,
                    'mail.default' => $settings->mail_driver,
                    'mail.from.address' => $settings->mail_username,
                    'mail.from.name' => $settings->mail_from,
                    'app.name' => $settings->site_name,
                    'app.url' => $settings->site_url,
                ]);
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Here is the controller method:

```
 public function updateConfig(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'mail_driver' => 'required',
            'mail_host' => 'required',
            'mail_port' => 'required|numeric',
            'mail_from' => 'required',
            'mail_encryption' => 'required',
            'mail_username' => 'required|email',
            'mail_password' => 'required',
        ]);
        $settings = Setting::find(1);
        $settings->update([
            'mail_driver' => $request->mail_driver,
            'mail_host' => $request->mail_host,
            'mail_port' => $request->mail_port,
            'mail_from' => $request->mail_from,
            'mail_encryption' => $request->mail_encryption,
            'mail_username' => $request->mail_username,
            'mail_password' => $request->mail_password,
        ]);
        $settings = Setting::find(1);
        try {
            Mail::to($settings->site_email)->send(new WelcomeEmail(false, 'Successful Email Configuration'));
            return response()->json([
                'success' => [
                    'title' => 'Success',
                    'message' => 'Email Settings Successfully Configured'
                ],
            ], 201);
        } catch (Throwable $th) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => [
                    'title' => 'Error',
                    'message' => 'Incorrect Email Configuration',
                ],
            ], 502);
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `env('APP_INSTALLED')`, because when you run `php artisan config:cache` in production, `env(...)` will ALWAYS return `null`. So change that part of the code to always be `config('whataver.config.index.you.want')`. And I did not understand where the error is. So, you are expecting that `$settings->update([...])` changes the config so the `WelcomeEail` is sent to the correct email?

Comment: Thanks for pointing the "env" error, i'll update it in my code.

I want the email config to update immediately as soon as I update the database and not use the previous database details instead of the updated one after which it will use the latest.

Comment: In that case, you have to either manually reset the data as you did on the service provider, or you have to put a `saved` event on the `Setting`'s model so when you save, you update the data automatically: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#events-using-closures use the `saved` event